# Stochastic integral with respect to negative time? Interpretation.

Tags: integration, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

Sometimes I see stochastic integrals of the form:
$$\int_{-\infty}^t f(t-u)dL_u,$$
where $L$ is a Lévy process. But I do not understand how this is defined. $L$ is just defined for positive times and $L_0=0$ so the filtration is such that $\mathcal{F}_0$ is trivial.

I have encountered this in many settings: Ornstein-Uhlenbeck processes, CARMA processes, Hawkes processes: $N_t$ with intensity $\lambda_t = \lambda + \int_{-\infty}^t g(t-u)dN_u$. Here, how is the latter integral to be understood if $N_u$ is just defined for $u\geq 0$?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Are you sure the lower integration bound is $-\infty\,?$ If so, where exactly did you see that? For a lower bound zero and with a Brownian motion the integral $\int_0^tt-s\,dW_s$ is easily seen to be $\int_0^tW_s\,ds\,.$ (Use integration by parts.)

Comment: Yes. For example here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_process#Hawkes_(self-exciting)_processes

Comment: I see. The idea is that the Hawkes process $N_t$ has a history that starts at $-\infty$. On he history until now it is deterministic. The history until $t$ determines the intensity for jumps in the next instant $t+dt\,.$ Wikipedia explains this well and gives references. I doubt however that the Hawkes process is a Levy process. Correct me if I am wrong and reference please in that case.

Comment: What is that history? As I understand $N$ starts at $0$ and $N_0=0$, $P$-a.s., isn't it? What does it then mean to integrate from $-\infty$ and what $\sigma$-algebra is it to be understood? No, Hawkes process is not Lévy, it is not Markov either.

Comment: Wikipedia gives you six references that I want you to consult. It is natural to assume that a process depends on its past (not Markov).  Therefore $N_0$ is not $0$ but depends on what it has done before $t=0\,.$ An Asian option in quant finance is similar.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm being clear in my question. See for example: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1507.02822.pdf there on Definition 5 of a Hawkes process, the process $N_t$ is defined on $[0,\infty)$. Then equation (3) makes sense to me: integral from $0$to $t$. But then, later on, equation (4) starts at $-\infty$. But what is $N_{s}$ for $s<0$, and $N_{-\infty}$? I know that the dependence on $[0,t]$ (like Asian options) is the past. But what is $N_s$ for negative $s$? How is this expression to be interpreted or understood?